# "Use of unresolved Identifier 'grey_accessibilityID' "

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation, earlgrey

[image]"compilation errors"

I was trying out EarlGrey on one of my apps as a POC. If that goes well, I was planning to use the same for the enterprise app that our company is working on.

I setup the framework as described in the github page. The link is https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/install-and-run.md

I followed all the steps and added EarlGrey.swift file too in my tests folder. Because it was the way the Demo project in EarlGrey project directory was setup. Unfortunately I started getting 13 compilation errors in EarlGrey.swift file. I was getting "Use of unresolved identifier grey_accessibilityID" errors all over. Snapshot attached.

I have tried most scenarios, please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: You should try taking a look at how they set up their demo project - https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/tree/master/Demo/EarlGreyExample

Comment: Even the sample projects had compilation errors when I tried to build after all the steps. Then I added import statement in EarlGrey.swift and test case class to avoid the compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing EarlGrey in the bridging header?
See `Swift` section in https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/install-and-run.md#swift

Update:
The fix was to rename the `EarlGrey-1.0.0` folder to `EarlGrey` that's downloaded by Pods and fix all the broken links in the xcode project.